# Python - Open file in Append Mode. Write Never Happens

Tags: python, file-io, append

I've been at this one for a couple days. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Open an already existing csv file in append mode
2. Add a string of new lines of csv to the bottom ('buffer' below)
3. Close the file
4. Rename the file reflecting the date of the last data entered.

Snippet of my code:

```
if mode == 'a':
    print buffer
    print fn
    f = open(fn,mode)
    f.write(buffer)
    #f.write("\nfoo,bar")
    f.close()
    print f.closed
    os.rename(".\\out\\" + fn, ".\\out\\" + fn[0:17]+tdy[0:4]+ "_" + tdy[5:7] + "_" + tdy[8:10] + ".csv")
```

Additional info:

- mode indeed == 'a' it gets to the loop.
- `buffer` prints. prints as a string of multiline csv data like:

  ```
  foo, bar, foo, bar
  foo, bar, foo, bar
  foo, bar, foo, bar
  ```
- `fn` is the correct filename I'm trying to open and prints as such.
- `f.closed` returns `True`
- `os.rename` works and renames the file. when I open it, buffer has not been appended.
- I've tried adding a `flush()` before close.
- I've tried it without the rename.
- I've tried to append a hard coded string.

Any ideas?

Comment: That approach should work, except for whatever's going on with the rename.  It looks to me like you're renaming a file which isn't the one you're writing to.  Could you make a smaller snippet, one that can be copied and pasted into a fresh interpreter, which shows the problem?

Comment: If you skip the `rename`, does the original file have the appended data?

Comment: Yup, y'all hit the nail on the head. Simple one where I was adding the directory to the path string in one instance and not in the other. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with *two* files here.

You open `fn` for writing in the *current* directory, but you rename the file `'.\out\' + fn`.

When opening `fn`, make sure you use the correct directory:

```
f = open(r'.\out\' + fn ,mode)
```

Note that on Windows, you can use the `/` separator as well, which is easier to deal with as you don't have to use raw strings or escape the slashes. Also, it's better to use `os.path.join()` to deal with directories and files:

```
filename = os.path.join('./out', fn)
```

then work with `filename` throughout the function.

Comment: Hah! Good catch. Shame on me for that one. I had about a hundred files created in the parent directory of the directory I was aiming for. Thanks